# convenient syntax for executing asynchronous functions if condition is met

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Recently, I ended up doing something along those lines to achieve the execution of asynchronous functions (async_1,async_2,async_3 must be executed in that order.)

```
if(async_1_possible)
{
    async_1()
        .then(function(result_1){
            if(async_2_possible)
            {
                async_2()
                    .then(function(result_2){
                    sync(result_2);
                    async_3(result_1);
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                async_3(result_1);
            }
        });
}
else
{
    if(async_2_possible)
    {
        async_2()
            .then(function(result_2){
            sync(result_2);
            async_3();
            });
    }
    else
    {
        async_3();
    }
}
```

That code can quickly become quite ugly... I am looking for a syntax allowing me to do this :

```
if(async_1_possible){var queue += async_1};
if(async_2_possible){var queue += function(result_1){async_2();}};
if(async_3_possible){var queue += function(result_2){sync(result_2);async_3(result_1)}};

run queue();
```

edit : modified example to show passing promises result to the next one and also executing sync functions

edit 2 : looked at q library, but still fail to see a painless way to achieve the kind of process described above

Comment: time to look into promises: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Assuming you use a promise library that follows the spec, `a.then(() => b.then(c))` should be equivalent to `a.then(b).then(c)`. If something fails, let the error propagate, and catch it at the end using the `.fail` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will look into jquery promises since I am already using jquery and it seems to be enough for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly look at control flow libraries such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and [step](https://github.com/creationix/step). These help you organize your async callbacks and code complex flows that's hell in asynchronous coding (e.g. queuing, loops with async functions inside, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Q then, you can do something like this

```
var funcs = [];
if (async_1_possible) {
    funcs.push(async_1);
}
if (async_2_possible) {
    funcs.push(async_2);
}
if (async_3_possible) {
    funcs.push(async_3);
}
funcs.reduce(Q.when, Q(initialVal));
```

[Q Documentation entry](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences) for the same

Comment: So this guarantees async_1 will be resolved before async_2 is launched, but jquery.when(async_1,async_2,async_3) does not guarantee the same?

Comment: Then we loose advantage of asynchronous functions, right?

Comment: Well not entirely, other stuff can run while every asynchronous function waits for the one before it.

Comment: I am afraid I dont follow you here; what I mean, is that I indeed want the functions to behave like synchronous functions locally but the whole bloc is still asynchronous. Like if I write a.then(b).then(c); d();, d() gets executed first, which would not be the case with synchronous functions.

Comment: You want the second asynchronous function to wait for the first async function, right?

Comment: Yes, but that does not make the sequence of functions synchronous

Comment: The sequence doesn't matter, if one function waits for the other function to complete, then they are running synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Well this looks stupid, but is somewhat useful if you do not want to use a specific library for promises so I thought I'd post it here :

```
var promises_string = "$.when()";
    if(async_1_possible)  
    {promises_string+=".then(function(){return async_1();})";}

    if(async_2_possible)
    {promises_string+=".then(function(result_1){return async_2();})";}
    promises_string+=".then(function(result_2){sync(result_2);
    if(sync_3_possible){return async_3;}return $.when();})";}
    etc..

eval(promises_string);
```

In case when you need a result from an asynchronous call 2 steps or more before (like async_3(result_1), this fails, but I guess writing a parser would not be too hard...